# Analysis problem (Let $f(x)$ be a $C^2$ function)

Tags: analysis

> Let $f(x)$ be a $C^2$ function.
>
> (a) Show that $\lim_{h \to 0} {f(3h)-3f(h)+2f(0)\over h^2}=3f''(0)$.
>
> (b) Assume $f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $h$. Prove that $f(x)=ax+b$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

---

For (a), I used L'Hospital rule to derive, but I got stuck in (b).

Here is my attempt:

$f(x+2h)-f(x+h)-\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\right)=0$,
for a fixed $h$, let $g(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$, then $g(x+h)-g(x)=0$,
so I find that $g(x)$ is a periodic function...

Thanks zhw, so appreciate for your proof.

Comment: What does g(x,y) have to do with it?

Comment: There are branch problem in (c) and (d) asking about g(x,y), buut I didn't ask (c) and (d), so that can be ignored.

Comment: So why include it?

Comment: Hint: write the definition of derivative for $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b): Fix $x.$ Then for any $h>0$ we have

$$ 0 = f(x+2h) - f(x+h) - [f(x+h) - f(x)] = f'(a_h)h - f'(b_h)h = f''(c_h)h(a_h-b_h).$$

Here I've used the mean value theorem twice.

This implies $f''=0$ somewhere in $(x,x+h)$ for any $h>0.$ Therefore $f''(x) = 0$ by contininuity of $f''.$ Thus $f''\equiv 0,$ which implies $f(x)=ax+b$ as desired.